# Collection<CaseItem> of entity CsgoItem[] not initialized when fetching count

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm

I have the following entity set up:

```
    @Entity()
export class CsgoItem extends CommonBaseEntity {
  @Property()
  name: string;

  @Property({ nullable: true })
  condition: string;

  @Property({ default: false })
  stattrack: boolean;

  @Enum({ items: () => RarityType })
  rarity: string;

  @Property({ length: 1000 })
  imageUrl: string;

  @Property({
    type: 'decimal',
    precision: 12,
    scale: 2,
    default: 0.0,
  })
  price: number;

  @OneToMany(() => CaseItem, (caseItem) => caseItem.csgoItem, {
    cascade: [Cascade.REMOVE],
  })
  caseItems = new Collection<CaseItem>(this);


  async getCaseItemsCount() {
   await this.caseItems.init(); // Ensure collection is initialized
    return this.caseItems.count();
  }
```

Service:

```
findAllWithArgs(args = {}) {
    return this.em.find(CsgoItem, {}, args);
  }
```

Controller:

```
    @Get('/admin')
  findAllWithArgs() {
    return this.csgoItemService.findAllWithArgs({
      fields: ['getCaseItemsCount'],
    });
  }
```

Where I try to fetch the amount of `caseItems` the `csgoItem` is found in, but no matter what I try, I keep on getting: `Collection<CaseItem> of entity CsgoItem[3d8a66ed-661d-4f40-8367-cca1ddbc3337] not initialized`, even when trying to force the initialization of the collection

Comment: did you try to always load relationship with eager https://mikro-orm.io/docs/decorators#onetomany ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not awaiting the `init` call, the collection is not initialized when you call `count()`.

Comment: When awaiting the init i get `caseItemsCount: {}` as response

Comment: When logging `console.log(this.caseItems.count());` it does show up though as a number

Comment: You cannot have an async properties in the first place, as serialization is sync. Try dropping the `@Property` decorator, and share your code.

Comment: Updated my question, if i remove the `@Property` decorator i get: `Entity 'CsgoItem' does not have property 'getCaseItemsCount`

Comment: Because you are trying to partially load if (the `fields` option), which obviously won't work, since its not a property you could load, its a method.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. Is there a way to achieve this in a property? For instance by using a formula?

Comment: Yeah you can use a lazy formula, that way you can populate the property to have the value.